# Take a value text not id value in dropdown list

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdownlist

```
<option value="13">MATT</option>
<option value="15">MeT</option>
```

I would like to take the text instead  id value from a dropdownlist:
what's wrong with this line??

```
if ($("select[title='" + tipologiaSelector + '"] ("option: selected")').text() == "MATT")
```

thank you

Comment: //<option value="13">MATT</option> 
//<option value="13">MeT</option>

Comment: Show your HTML in order to know what's wrong with that line.

Comment: <option value="13">MATT</option>

Comment: show full html with <select></select>

Answer (score 0):

You can get `value` of `option` by text by `spread` operator and `find` as

```
var res = [...document.getElementsByTagName("option")].find(c=>c.innerText == "MATT").value;
```

If you want to use jquery, use `each` function as

```
$("#test option").each(function(index, item){
  if( $(item).text() == "MATT") {
      id = $(item).attr("value");
      return;
  }
})
```

```js
var res = [...document.getElementsByTagName("option")].find(c=>c.innerText == "MATT").value;
console.log(res)

var id;
$("#test option").each(function(index, item){
  if( $(item).text() == "MATT") {
      id = $(item).attr("value");
      return;
  }
})

console.log(id)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
<option value="13">MATT</option>
<option value="15">MeT</option>
</select>
```

Comment: but a possibility in jquery or javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Your selector has the wrong syntax.  unmatched quotes: `title='"` and spacing after `:` and no need for paranthesis and quotes around the `option:selected`.

```js
tipologiaSelector = "mytitle";

if ($("select[title=\"" + tipologiaSelector + '"] option:selected').text() == "MATT") console.log("== MATT");

$('select').change( function(){

if ($("select[title=\"" + tipologiaSelector + '"] option:selected').text() == "MATT") console.log("== MATT");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select title="mytitle">
<option value="13">MATT</option>
<option value="15">MeT</option>
</select>
```